# Automatic selection of <p></p>-text rendered in browser

Tags: javascript, html, text, selection

who would know of a possibility to automatically select Paragaph text as it gets rendered in a browser, preferably using JavaScript?

In my case I have an amount of text in `<p></p>` tags and would like the page to appear with the text fully selected, just as if someone had done it manually with the mouse.

Many thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

Insert this near the very end of your page:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

ptags = window.document.getElementsByTagName("p");
current_selection = window.getSelection();

for (i=0; i< ptags.length; i++)
{
    var r1 = document.createRange();
    r1.setStartBefore(ptags[i]);
    r1.setEndAfter(ptags[i]) ;
    current_selection.addRange(r1);
}

</script>
```

Tested in Firefox 3.07 --> not really sure about cross-browser compatibility, although I think IE should be all right.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [article](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html), the [W3C range](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range-20001113/ranges.html) (ChristopheD's code) isn't supported by IE6/7, so you'll have to do a browser check and use [createTextRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535872.aspx) for IE6/7.

As a small addition, maybe you could define a function to encapsulate the code written by ChristopheD and do something like `<body onload="selectPs()">` or maybe `$(document).ready(function() {});` if you use jQuery. May be more effective than placing the script at the end of the html code.